# Deleting contacts from both the Google Account and Android device

Tags: android-10, google-pixel-4a

I was trying to remove all the useless contacts from my Google Account, hoping that they will be permanently deleted. **I disabled Sync option in my Smart phone prior to that**.

But, the contacts keep getting synched to the Google Account. Is there any getaway ?

Comment: 1. Disable data on your phone. 2. Use any contact cleaner app from Play Store /any other source and delete your contacts on phone 3. [Export to vcf, cleanup unwanted contacts and import](https://support.google.com/contacts/answer/7199294?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&oco=1) 4. Enable data and sync your phone 5. Revert with results :)

Comment: @beeshyams If I delete contacts from the contacts web page, will they be deleted from my phone?

Comment: They should ideally IMO but method above is preferred because your phone seems to be sync despite disabling// In step 2 above simply delete the contacts app data, stupid of me to suggest using an app :( // Sync shouldn't happen but you say you disabled it, yet it syncs - weird